# How to show Results marks in round pie chart style in javascript quiz?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello friends i have a javascript quiz, 
currently in my quiz results showing in this format
You Give 2 Correct Answer Out Of 10 (Percentage Is 20%)

it is the javascrit code

```
$('#question').addClass("sub-header").text("You give " + score + " correct answer out of " + quiz.questions.length + " (Percentage is " + percentageCorrect + "%)");
```

but i dont know how show add result in pie chart like this.
[easypiechart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VopKI.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eeaNoq?page=2).
Have modified example 1 for 20%

you have to make use of data-start,data-value which are HTML5 custom data attributes

```
<div class="demo-wrapper">
<div class="csspie" data-start="0" data-value="20"></div>
<div class="csspie big" data-start="20" data-value="80"></div>
</div>
```